# Cant connect to my server through ssh

Tags: server, virtualbox, ssh, hosts

My problem is as follows. I have a made VM(Ubuntu Server) and I have edited the `hosts.allow/deny` for `limited access`. However, now I can't connect from my PC through `ssh` to the server. What should I add to the `hosts.allow` file to allow my PC connect with `ssh` to the server ? One of the adds is this:

```
ALL: 127.0.0: allow
```

and still can't connect.

Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: have you tried `ufw`?

Comment: i dont know this command. I shall do this with my port ?

Comment: It's not command, it's an app.install it with `sudo apt-get install ufw`

Comment: once i do whats next ?

Comment: read `man ufw`. I use `gufw`(graphical interface) as a firewall for my computer. ufw gives you options such as allow,deny,reject for specific ports and IP's.Everything else, you probably know more than I do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `ALL : 192.168.1.0/255.255.254.0` instead. This allows all machines on the local network.

Comment: didnt work for me .

Comment: My bad, it should be without the `: allow` at the end of the line.